# How to run large amounts of STOCKHISTORY function without file crashing? Perhaps Font, # of workbooks, # of file references?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

So I'm using the new STOCKHISTORY function in excel, however, I need to run around 1700-2100 separate calculations. Every time I start building the excel file about halfway through it gets to a point where the file crashes after I do almost anything. The total number of cells used would be in the 950,000-1,050,000 range (Not all are STOCKHISTORY, some are regular formulas). On my first try the file got to 20mb but then I couldn't even open it. So I tried a second time and took some advice to shrink the file size but now that I'm halfway through creating it the file crashes after I do almost anything. It's currently only 5mb though. This could be a problem with the fact that I'm on the Insider Fast program which could mean it's unoptimized or it could be part in fact that I querying 1700-2100 separate STOCKHISTORY functions. Either way I'm looking for some ideas to shrink the file size and/or make the process faster.

I've done the following

- Pasted the formulas into a new Excel file to get rid of excess blank rows & columns
- When pasting got rid of borders
- Limited cell references when the value could be static
- Chopped up the functions into 7 workbooks
- Made all the fonts the same and size of font the same.

I've got a whole bunch of scenarios that I'm unsure would be helpful or not. For example is there a specific font/font-size that takes less file space and/or loading speed. Is having all the formulas and info in 1 workbook compared to 5 or 10 workbooks better for speed? What about if instead of having all the functions and formulas in one file I chopped up the information into 2-5 different files and made a master file. Does that alleviate speed and/or usability? I could theoretically cut down the total number of STOCKHISTORY functions to only 1000-1200 but that wouldn't be super ideal. What about specific file types like .xlsb, .xlsx or .xlsm. Which of those (or others) would be able to run the calculations faster or have a smaller file size? What about splitting formulas into multiple cells compared to one big formulas, does that have an effect?

Comment: Tbh, with that much data sounds like you're using the wrong tool. Excel just isn't suitable for that sort of scenario.

Comment: Theoretically this could be the case. I'm just unsure where I would go to both A. Get the data and be able to refresh it based on certain characteristics and B. Be able to calculate things about the data.

Comment: Python would be my first recommendation.

Comment: I've got no knowledge in programming languages so undertaking that task would be massive and take a longg time. It's frustrating because I've figured out all the results and information I want in the Excel file, I just can't open it...